# Why won't my replacement motor run at full speed when changing the direction of rotation?

Tags: hvac, installation, troubleshooting

Our 1/4 HP motor went out in our A/C today. I got a replacement 1/6 to 1/2 HP motor. 120v with ccw and cw capability.

When I installed it worked great but spun the wrong direction. When I switched the required wires to reverse the direction it only runs at half speed now.

Any idea why this would be? I replaced a capacitor as well and also tried the old to make sure.

When I switch directions again it runs at full speed again.

Comment: how is this home improvement question

Comment: What is the model number of the motor? What is it running? Is it possible it's spinning a fan that is harder to turn in one direction?

Comment: When you were running it in the wrong direction did you have it connected to a fan that wasspinning in the wrong direction AND overspeeded because it was not loaded? Fans, especialy squirrel cage fans, are asymmetrical and would not provide much resistance if spun backwards. This might make the motor run faster in reverse than in the forward direction. Running the motor backwards could even result in overspeed damage, but for me this is only speculation. I dont know enough about motors to know if this is a real possibility.

Comment: Is this the fan motor the one in the condensing unit outside or the one in the air handler inside? Is this a single speed fan or a multispeed fan? Most condensing units use a single speed fan but AFIK many (nearly all?) air handlers use at least a dual speed fan. These air handlers are set up to use a lower speed in the heating mode and a higher speed in the a/c refrigeration mode.